# Karabiner elements custom complex rule

Tags: keyboard, keybindings, karabiner

I have a busted close-bracket key on my keyboard. Previously, I had used Karabiner to map L-control+open_bracket to close_bracket using a custom rule I wrote in the xml-format used by karabiner.

However, now that I've updated to Sierra, Karabiner is out, and Karabiner elements is in. Karabiner elements uses a JSON format. I tried to create a new rule and stick it in the JSON file:

```
"rules": [
         {"manipulators": [
                {"description": "bracket rule",
                        "from": {"key_code": "open_bracket", 
                                 "modifiers": ["left_control"]
                                },
                          "to": [{"key_code": "close_bracket",
                                  "modifiers":[]
                                }] 
                }         ]
         }]
```

However, this rule doesn't seem to work the way I'd like it to (it just maps open_bracket to close_bracket).

Does anyone have an insight into what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you contacted the developer of the application to ask for support?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your sample appeared to be slightly different than other rules I've looked at.  Here's a version that works for me:

file: map_lctl_plus_open_bracket_to_close_bracket.json :

```
{
  "title": "Map Lft-Ctl+Open-Bracket to Close-Bracket",
  "rules": [
    {
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "description": "bracket rule",
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "open_bracket",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "left_control"
              ],
              "optional": [
                "caps_lock"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "close_bracket"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I wasn't able to determine any way to install the script other than through the `"Import more rules from the internet"` option, but I did figure out how to launch the importer on my own files.

Assuming you copy the file into `/tmp/map_lctl_plus_open_bracket_to_close_bracket.json`, pasting the following url into Safari should launch the importer:

`karabiner://karabiner/assets/complex_modifications/import?url=file%3A%2F%2F%2Ftmp%2Fmap_lctl_plus_open_bracket_to_close_bracket.json`

I have fully tested both the file content and the import url within this post, and all worked fine for me.

Good luck !

---

EDIT: Immediately after making this post, I think I found where the local filestore is for manually adding rules.

https://github.com/pqrs-org/KE-complex_modifications#local-testing

This is the github repo for the rules on the `"Import more rules from the internet"` page.  It shows how to test the rules locally before submitting to the web repository.

TL;DR:

```
$ cp my_rule.json ~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications
```

The site also confirms the `karabiner://...` technique I mentioned above.

Comment: I find it much easier to edit Karabiner's JSON file directly at:

~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json

with TextEdit.
If you make a mistake, Karabiner Elements will no longer show any scripts/modifications in its "Karabiner-Elements Preferences" window.
S you can "debug" your changes/additions by watching this window while you save your text – and undo some steps …

Comment: You can also drop the JSON file in ~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications and it will appear in complex modifications when you press the add button.

Comment: OMFG how bad is the Karabiner-Elements doc?! "It will appear when you press the add button". Absolute gold. Now I've managed to import my simple little config without making a pull request to a GitHub repo. Thank you very much @DarrelHolt

Comment: weirdly, I couldn't get it working by moving the file into the config directory (even though the correct directory was created by the app) but the `karabiner://` method works.

Answer (score 1):

Your own code simply leaves out the key word "mandatory" in combination with "left_control" – so Karabiner EACH time is content to register only "open_bracket" to remap the key to "close_bracket".

EDIT, … much later: you also ***need*** to code `"type": "basic"` in every manipulator !

Note: there is a complementary key word "optional" that may be default in lack of "mandatory"…